# Install ubuntu packages to other machine?

Tags: 12.04, installation, package-management, clone

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop with all the packages. I am finished with it, everything is up and running.

Now i want to install Ubuntu on my desktop but don't want to download all the stuff again and install it one by one. Is there any way to clone my ubuntu from laptop to desktop.

Answer (score 0):

https://superuser.com/questions/378686/when-you-do-apt-get-install-where-are-the-deb-files-stored. This question tells you where the package files are stored. Copy them across and install from them. Or clone your hard drive. This is a guide http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/2-methods-to-clone-your-linux-hard-drive/  but moving the packages may be best over network

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make a distro disc to install the packages from. [remastersys livecd](http://www.remastersys.com/)

Comment: This does not explain *how* to do it. Moreover, does this really clone the current installation as the OP is asking for?